# does currentContentSizeIdentifier exist in iOS 4.0 and 4.1

Tags: iphone, ios4

I have the following code for iAds.

```
[_iAdAdView setCurrentContentSizeIdentifier:ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait];
```

But this code throws "EXC_BAD_ACCESSS" in iOS 4.0 and iOS 4.1 devices.

The doc says that it is available from iOS 4.0 and later
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/Reference/ADBannerView_Ref/Reference/Reference.html

So why does the code crash for iOS 4.0 and iOS 4.1 and not for iOS 4.2 and later.

How do I work around to set the required settings for iOS 4.0 and iOS 4.1.

**EDIT:
I found the solution in the source code AdBannerView.h, and noticed that "ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait" is availabled only in iOS 4.2**

Comment: EXC_BAD_ACCESS doesn't mean that the code is not supported or doesn't exist in that version, it means that the _iAdAdView object is over-released or not present any more or not initialized.

Comment: it 'indicates' so when the code works on one OS version and not on another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution in the source code AdBannerView.h, and noticed that "ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait" is availabled only in iOS 4.2

Answer (score 2):

This is what the documentation says

> The identifier placed in the currentContentSizeIdentifier property
>   must be included in the set of identifiers stored in the
>   requiredContentSizeIdentifiers property. This ensures that an
>   advertisement displayed by the view can still be displayed after the
>   view’s size changes. **Setting a value not included in the
>   requiredContentSizeIdentifiers property causes an exception to be
>   thrown.**

Check out the bold part. That is what might be causing the exception.

Comment: you are right, have posted a related question then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8223763/adbannercontentsizeidentifier320x50-deprecated-now-what